# C# Unity3D - Чекпоинт

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Как можно сделать невидимые чекпоинты, и когда персонаж проходит через них, у него появляются новые способности(Например: в коде, персонаж умеет стрелять пулями/получать урон и т.д., но эта возможность заблокирована, пока он не дойдет до невидимой зоны, после чего способность останется до конца сцены)? Я искал это в гугле, но нашел только: "как сделать чекпоинты сохранения игры".

P.S. Я новичок в этой сфере, желательно примеры кода

Comment: гугли Collider, isTrigger, OnTriggerEnter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как правильно заметили в комментариях под вопросом, нужно смотреть в сторону колайдеров и тригеров. Что бы долго не мучатся, [вот](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/collecting-pick-objects) есть туториал от Unity.

В целом, вся магия происходит при столкновении объектов в вот этом методе

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Pick Up"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

Проверив тэги (пока не понятно зачем они - их можно опустить), вы выключаете объект пик-апа и здесь же можете написать логику, которая будет выполняться в зависимости от типа пик-апа.

В целом, лучше всего такую логику держать в компоненте пик-апа, что бы он знал что делать, а не персонаж, как в данном примере.

Comment: Более тривиальный путь - Vector3 и Distance между персонажем и контрольной точкой. Сама скалярная дистанция - это радиус сферы зоны чекпоинта. В момент когда персонаж входит в радиус, скрипт который выполняет проверку надо удалить. Ну, имхо, такой подход будет пошустрее и оптимальнее чем коллидеры + не требует настроек цели/target-а, не нужна физика, и не надо смотреть на интерсекцию полигонов и коллидера.

Comment: Хотя, забивать гвозди микроскопом и закручивать их отвёрткой - типичное поведение Unity3D программистов :)

Comment: @test123, конечно, такой подход тоже можно реализовать. Но это писать логику нужно, которая уже реализованная в движок, что не очень правильно. Да и думать о таких оптимизациях без собственно проблем с оптимизацией не стоит.

Comment: Как раз, конкретно в этом случае, коллидер только мешает. Как вы предлагаете бороться с тем, что все коллидеры проверяют пересечение не относительно вашего персонажа, а с любым, помеченным как target, объектом в текущей сцене? Хотя, согласен, можно просто забить на это, и отхватить проблему с этим позже. Написать строчку с вычислением дистанции и блоком условия - для вас это называется сложная логика? Ну, оберните это в один MonoBehaviour, если так жаждите спрятать низкоуровневый подход. В любом случае, это проще чем коллидер. Для добавления коллидера вам всё равно нужен компонент.

Comment: @test123, можно написать всю логику Unity3d собственными компонентами, либо написать свой движок. Либо писать игры:) Если немного изучить подробнее этот вопрос, окажется, что сферические колайдеры по сути работают по принципу пересечения по дистанции - так все колайдеры устроены, но с дополнительными плоскостями вычисления чуть сложнее. "Бороться" с этим помогают тригеры, слои пересечения и тэги. А почему это плохо писать - не потому, что сложно или лень, а потому что чем больше кода, тем больше ошибок, тем сложнее этот код поддерживать.

Comment: Я говорю ровно о том же. Добавление коллайдера - это от 3 методов, включая Start и Update, с ними ещё и OnTriggerEnter/OnCollisionEnter, отсев лишних объектов и 90% функционала, который мы умышленно атрофируем. Далее, читаем док https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html Обращаю внимание на >>Trigger events are only sent if one of the Colliders also has a Rigidbody attached<< Сложность и условности растут на глазах, не правда ли? Шанс напороться на невнимательность - в разы выше чем в коде if(Vector3.Distantion(transform.position, target.position) >= RADIUS) { ...

Comment: @test123, вижу что по поводу сложности каждый останется при своём мнении:) Могу только заметить, что OnTriggerEnter для своей работы требует все же только один метод, а не от 3х.